# CSS Spritesheet animation keeps moving towards the left

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a spritesheet (9170px x 350px) that has 70 frames of a single character. Here's my code.

```css
@-webkit-keyframes play {
  100% {
    background-position: -9170px;
  }
}
@keyframes play {
  100% {
    background-position: -9170px;
  }
}
.character-one {
  width: 131px;
  height: 350px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-left: 20px;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/gK3C2VZ.png') left center;
  -webkit-animation: play 2s steps(70) infinite;
  animation: play 2s steps(70) infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="character-one"></div>
```

When I open it in the browser, I see the character getting animated, but the spritesheet moves from right to left inside the div that's there. What could the reason be? I figured that normally happens when the `steps()` are fewer than the number of frames, but in my case everything seems to be OK. Could it be that the frames are not evenly spaced?

Here's the link to the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/spz330h8/1/)

Comment: Can you upload spritesheet_wide.png so that we can see the problem?

Comment: @Harry Added link to the question description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though your actual sprite-sheet is 9170px wide, the individual sprites within it actually have a margin on either side. This is what is causing the sliding effect.

As per your code, there are 70 steps and the background moves by 9170px (which is 131px for each step). But each 131px of the sprite don't seem to exactly overlap one another. In the below image, we can see how the first 131px of the spritesheet and the last 131px look like (background added just for visual distinction).

[image]

Changing the `background-position` like in the below snippet seems to produce a much better output.

```css
@-webkit-keyframes play {
  100% {
    background-position: -9144px;
  }
}

@keyframes play {
  100% {
    background-position: -9144px;
  }
}

.character-one {
  width: 131px;
  height: 350px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-left: 20px;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/gK3C2VZ.png');
  background-position: -28px center;
  -webkit-animation: play 2s steps(70) infinite;
  animation: play 2s steps(70) infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="character-one"></div>
```

---

In the below sprite-sheet, we can see how there is equal spacing on all sides for each sprite image. It is taken from the [Tree House blog on CSS Sprite Sheet Animations](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/css-sprite-sheet-animations-steps).

[image]

Comment: Would having a fixed width of 131px for each frame (without margins) solve the problem?

Comment: @sarath: By margin, I was referring to the space within the image in front and back (see the image I have added into the answer). If you can update your spritesheet to have exactly the same amount of pixels for each image then it should be fine. That is the person's image within first 131px should exactly overlap his image in the last 131px (and for each 131px in between also). If that is done, then there would be no issues.

Comment: You can see how [**this spritesheet**](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/monster.png) has equal spacing. It is taken fro this blog - http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/css-sprite-sheet-animations-steps.

Comment: @sarath: Did that help or are you looking for any more info? If it helped, please consider accepting the answer (click the hollow tick mark below the voting buttons). If you need any more clarification, let me know your question.

Answer (score 0):

Sprite images are wrong sliced, distance is vary in all images. Please update sprite images then problem is solved.